# How to position absolute element vertically in the center?

Tags: html, css

As you can see in the snippet below, I have a `.square-container` which is positioned absolutely and it contains a square. I'm trying to vertically position the `.square-container` in the center of the parent div.

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}
.square-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
.square {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
.hello {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <p class='hello'>Hello</p>
    <div class="square-container">
        <div class='square'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For the absolute element, use `left: 50%; top: 50%;` to position the square's top-left corner in the middle of the blue element. Then use `margin-left: -15px; margin-top: -15px;` to position it's center in the center of the blue element (15px being half the square's extent). This should work just fine when the element to be centered is absolute, with fixed size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For positioning absolute elements in the middle use  `top: 50%`

And then use `transform: translateY(-50%);` and its centered

```css
.container {
        position: relative;
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .square-container {
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        top: 50%;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
       
    }
    .square {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: red;
    }
    .hello {
        padding: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <p class='hello'>Hello</p>
    <div class="square-container">
        <div class='square'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need absolute positioning here. If you set the `container` as a flex wrapper, you won't also need to position it relatively and can get rid of the `square-container` div as well that currently wraps the `div.square` element.

To push the square to the right, we could

A) use auto-margins inside the flex layout. So all that our `div.square` needs, is `margin-left: auto`, which tells the browser to push it as far as possible from its left siblings.

B) Use `justify-content: space-between` on our container. This tells the flex container to space out the elements to the sides.

The approaches differ very slightly and don't really matter in this example until we start adding more elements.

An updated example:

`A`

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: skyblue;
    padding: 15px;
}
.square {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <p class='hello'>Hello</p>
    <div class='square'></div>
</div>
```

`B`

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: skyblue;
    padding: 15px;
}
.square {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <p class='hello'>Hello</p>
    <div class='square'></div>
</div>
```